# can stormcrawler have different status index for each topology?

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler

I'm crawling about 20 domains and eventually scale to 300. Each domain has its own parser config, submitted as individual topologies.

So when using a single status index, all the topologies seem to pick up urls randomly without being specific to a particular domain.

Hence will having a separate status index for each topology solve the issue ? are there any other approaches to this ?

Also I cannot use a single topology for all domains as the crawl rates are different, also time of crawl and each domain is far different than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have one index per crawl, however, if you want to run 1 topology per domain, it would be a lot simpler to simply add 1 arbitrary metadata to the seed of the crawl and make sure that it gets [transferred](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/crawler-conf.yaml#L25) to the outlinks. You can then use [one filter query for each topology](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml#L44) so that the spout gets URLs for that crawl only. The metadata key could be something like *crawlID* for instance.

> Also I cannot use a single topology for all domains as the crawl rates are different, also time of crawl and each domain is far different than the other.

There is probably a way around this. Having a single topology would make things a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks Julien, I used a filter query based on the hostname field and it worked as expected !!